# Memory error when doing machine learning in Python Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, memory, pandas, machine-learning, out-of-memory

I am trying to do a machine learning training/testing by sampling 100,000 rows of data from a larger DataFrame. I have tried with 30,000-60,000 random sample with expected outputs, but when increasing to 100,000+ it is giving me memory error.

```
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np
import nltk
import re
import random
from random import randint
import csv
import dask.dataframe as dd
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

lr = LogisticRegression()
dv = DictVectorizer()
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=0, encoding="utf-8")
df = DataFrame(data)

# Random sampling a smaller dataframe for debugging
rows = random.sample(df.index, 100000)
df = df.ix[rows] # Warning!!!! overwriting original df

# Assign X and y variables
X = df.raw_name.values
y = df.ethnicity2.values

# Feature extraction functions
def feature_full_last_name(nameString):
    try:
        last_name = nameString.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
        if len(last_name) > 1: # not accept name with only 1 character
            return last_name
        else: return '?'
    except: return '?'

# Transform format of X variables, and spit out a numpy array for all features
my_dict = [{'last-name': feature_full_last_name(i)} for i in X]

all_dict = my_dict

newX = dv.fit_transform(all_dict).toarray()

# Separate the training and testing data sets
half_cut = int(len(df)/2.0)*-1
X_train = newX[:half_cut]
X_test = newX[half_cut:]
y_train = y[:half_cut]
y_test = y[half_cut:]

# Fitting X and y into model, using training data
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Making predictions using trained data
y_train_predictions = lr.predict(X_train)
y_test_predictions = lr.predict(X_test)

print (y_train_predictions == y_train).sum().astype(float)/(y_train.shape[0])
print (y_test_predictions == y_test).sum().astype(float)/(y_test.shape[0])
```

Error statement:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dropbox\Python_Exercises\_Scraping\BeautifulSoup\FamilySearch.org\FamSearch_Analysis\MachineLearning\FamSearch_LogReg_GOOD8.py", line 93, in <module>
    newX = dv.fit_transform(all_dict).toarray()
  File "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 942, in toarray
    return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
  File "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 274, in toarray
    B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 793, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: I have 16.0 GB memory. And my python is 2.7.6 [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: How many columns are in the data?  What are the datatypes?  What is the size of the original data where your read from csv and then sample 100k rows?  This dataframe still exists in memory, so you may want to delete it after sampling before proceeding with your analysis.  In fact, `data` itself probably still exists.  Delete that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
newX = dv.fit_transform(all_dict).toarray()
```

Because almost all estimators in scikit-learn support sparse dataset, but you are trying to make dense from your sparse dataset. Of course it will consume big amount of memory. You need to avoid todense() and toarray() methods in your code.

Comment: I am not sure how else to prepare the format of the data to be trained by ML classifier otherwise, please advise.

Comment: @KubiK888, just remove '.toarray()' from that line, i think everything else will still work.